# Maximization of quadratic forms in R with respect to a vector of weights

Tags: r, optimization, algebra, maximize, quadratic-programming

I have a distance (similarity) matrix **D**, for example,

```
D <- matrix(c(0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.10, 0.05, 1.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.90, 0.95, 0.10, 1.00, 0.90, 0.00, 0.15, 0.05, 1.00, 0.95, 0.15, 0.00),5,5)
```

and a vector of weights **w** = (w1, ..., wn) such that sum(**w**) == 1. The values in the vector **w** are real and between 0 and 1, inclusively. I need to find a vector **w** such that the sum **w*****D***t(**w**) is maximized. Where t(**w**) is the transpose of **w** and the symbol "*" denotes matrix multiplication.

Amazingly enough, I can't find a solver that can do this in R.

Thank you

Comment: @chinsoon12, I think you're right. See for example section 'Quadratic forms on the unit sphere'  [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/Notes/QuadraticForms.pdf).

Comment: @chinsoon12 I  guess `eigen(D)$vectors[,1]` ignored the constraints `sum(w)=1` and `0 <=w<=1`

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, if the maximization problem is non-constrained, then I believe your approach with `eigen` is the most elegant one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try `fmincon` from package `pracma`, e.g.,

```
library(pracma)
D <- matrix(c(0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.10, 0.05, 1.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.90, 0.95, 0.10, 1.00, 0.90, 0.00, 0.15, 0.05, 1.00, 0.95, 0.15, 0.00),5,5)
n <- dim(D)[1]
res <- fmincon(rep(1,n),
               fn = function(w) -t(w)%*%D%*%w, 
               A = t(rep(1,n)), 
               b = 1,
               lb = rep(0,n),
               ub = rep(1,n))
w <- res$par
```

and you will get

```
> w
[1] 3.333331e-01 3.333338e-01 3.333331e-01 7.008297e-22 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: With starting vector `x0 = rep(1,n)` all solutions `w` are positive.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, it is! I updated my answer. I was using `matrix(rep(1,n)/n)` since I am not sure if `A*x0 = b` will be checked over the initial vector, so I want to play it safe :)

Comment: Thank you very much!!